# .NET resource file binding culture is wrong

Tags: c#, resources, bind, .net-assembly

I’m a newbie in .NET topics. I have created some forms  which are using language resource files.
And during binding the following is happening and I do not know where the language „de-DE” is set

In default log categoriy:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/28/2015 @ 4:40:24 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Prg\sample.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = MyForms.1.41.resources, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=de-DE, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/ Prg/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = sample.exe
Calling assembly : MyForms.1.41, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= xxxxxxxxxx.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Prg\sample.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: MyForms.1.41.resources, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=de-DE, PublicKeyToken= xxxxxxxxxx
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Prg/de-DE/MyForms.1.41.resources.DLL.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Now I have the needed file located under “de” directory and NOT under “de-DE” directory as searched in URL!

I have also invoked the Al.exe with flag **/culture:de**  on MyForms.1.41.resources  but no joy.

Any help is appreciated.

I cannot use directory “de-DE”  so overwrite of directory name is not possible,  “de” is a must.
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a possibility to set programmatically the culture for the resource files:

```
Thread.CurrentUICulture Property
```

As described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In my case the default culture was set to de-DE and the current culture was read from reg key. Unfortunately the reg key was missing, therefore the default one was used.
Cheers ...